# Wrapping HTML within a DIV

Tags: jquery

I have a variable a columns_output that generates HTML code, once its generates all code through loop, I want to wrap all code within one DIV, I have tried the following, however it shows "object object".

```
 columns_output = $('<div/>', {'class': 'section'}).append( columns_output );
```

OR

```
  columns_output = $(this).wrap('<div class="section"></div>');
```

the desired output is

```
 <div class="section"> Any HTML within columns_output</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this `$(sel).wrapAll("<div class='section'></div>");` 
Note : sel is the element that you are wrapping.